# Auto-compress SFTP file-transfer to reduce network data usage

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, compression, file-transfer

When downloading `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` (100 MB) from a distant server to my local computer via SFTP, I noticed that **the network transfer was not compressed**.

Indeed similar compressed files are ~ 10 MB and it would have taken 1/10th of the downloading time I observed.

**Is there an option in SSH/SFTP settings to auto-compress file transfer to reduce bandwidth and uploading/downloading time?**

(The server has Ubuntu and the local computer is using Win + WinSCP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On WinSCP, transport compression can be enabled in the SSH page on the [Advanced Site Settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_ssh) dialog:

[image]

For an OpenSSH command line client, the `-C` option to `sftp` (passed through as the `-C` option to `ssh`) provides transport compression for the session.

Comment: Wonderful, this simple option speeds up massively the transfer indeed. (PS: why isn't it the default setting?)

Comment: According to the `man` it slows down fast connections.